# How do I sort the words in a vector in alphabetical order?, (all letters in each word need to be accounted for)

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++17

I'm trying to make a function that sorts the words in a vector and puts them in alphabetical order, and if the letters are all the same letters the word with fewest letters ends up higher in the vector.

Right now everything seems to work except when words with all the same letters end up in a random order.

For  examlpe the words `a`, `aaa` and `aaaa` would end up in a random order, but I would want `a` to be at the top of the list and `aaaa` at the bottom.

```
void sortWords()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < wordList.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < wordList.size(); j++)
        {
            string temp;
            for (int y = 0; y < wordList[i].size(); y++)
            {
                if (wordList[i][y] < wordList[j][y] && i != j) 
                {
                    temp = wordList[i];
                    wordList[i] = wordList[j];
                    wordList[j] = temp;
                    break;
                }
                else if (wordList[i][y] > wordList[j][y] && i != j)
                {
                    break;
                }

            }
                
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you use `std::sort` with appropriate comparer?

Comment: *"in alphabetical order, and if the letters are all the same letters the word with fewest letters"*. With default std::string comparer "a" < "aaa" < "aaaaa".

Answer (score 1):

> How do i sort the words in a vector in alphabetical order?

With std, it would simply be

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

void sortWords(std::vector<std::string>& words)
{
    std::sort(words.begin(), words.end());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You write `wordList[j][y]` without checking whether `y <= wordList[j].size()` first. This is a potential error: using [std::string::operator[]](https://cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator%5B%5D/) with index greater than size() causes undefined behavior. You should never, ever allow this - always check whether you're out of array bounds before accessing an array. Once you account for that, your comparison subroutine will work correctly. In a separate function:

```
// <0 if a<b, >0 if a>b, =0 if a and b are the same, same logic as strcmp()
int compareLexicographic(const std::string& a, const std::string& b){
  //use size_t as index type
  for(size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i){
    if(i == b.size()) return 1; //b is over, a still isn't
    //now we can access a[i] and b[i]
    if(a[i] < b[i]) return -1;
    if(a[i] > b[i]) return 1;
  }
  //reached the end of a
  if(a.size() == b.size()) return 0;
  else return -1;
}
```

(As a side note, it's better to pass a pointer to `wordList` as an argument of `sortWords()`. Functions modifying global variables with little indication on the caller side make debugging very frustrating, you probably don't want to do this to yourself.)

Comment: perhaps worth mentioning that `std::string` is special. As you correctly write, using index greater than `size` is UB, but in general for arrays it is indices greater or equal that cause UB

Comment: [`std::lexicographic_compare`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lexicographical_compare) exists (and default comparer for `std::string` also do the job.

Comment: @Jarod42 Well, true, but judging by both the code provided and the errors I believe the request is "how do I reduce this task to primitive operations I understand", not "how do I combine a few high-level elements to achieve this result".